# Functions: Objects or many parameters - OOP

Tags: oop

I have a question to OOP in general. I'd like to demonstrate a snippet of code:

```
public class Test
{
    private int someInt = 0;

    public Test()
    {
        this.method1(this);
        this.method2(this.getSomeInt());
    }

    public void method1(Test test)
    {
        System.out.print(test.getSomeInt());
    }

    public void method2(int someInt)
    {
        System.out.print(someInt);
    }

    public int getSomeInt()
    {
        return this.someInt;
    }
}
```

My question here: Which of those two function calls is more efficient? Does it matter if I use the getter as a parameter or should I give the object as the parameter from the beginning? Could you explain which one I should prefer because I don't really know what to stick to. The object seems to be too big as a parameter, the parameters look too cascaded. I apologize in advance if any related question has been asked already, I didn't know what to look for. ,_,

Comment: and you can't inherit your classes from the base class? i.e. `FirstClass : Test`

Comment: Wait... I should use functions when I am talking about functions, my bad... going to correct it in a sec.

Comment: and the parameter passed to the method is from the same instance than the method itself and isn't static?

Comment: This is just sample code. My question is whether it is better to use an object as function parameter or extract the essential values beforehand. Like I mentioned, I think objects are too big and getter too cascaded, so I don't know.